# MacOS: Include files in C - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c, macos, gcc, linker

I am currently trying to compile a project with multiple files using GCC on MacOS High Sierra. For some reasons, I get the following error:

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.13.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -target-linker-version 302.3 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -resource-dir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0 -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/emmanuel/Desktop/ITC/C/Arrays/stackoverflow -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 151 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.13.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/j5/1q3h2809043fnwb6c83ycj9c0000gn/T/main-0c855d.o -x c main.c
clang -cc1 version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38) default target x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.13.0 -o a.out /var/folders/j5/1q3h2809043fnwb6c83ycj9c0000gn/T/main-0c855d.o -lSystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_myFunction", referenced from:
      _main in main-0c855d.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my code (I simplified it, so that it is more readable. I checked that it actually generates the error above):

main.c

```
#include "myfile.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    myFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

myfile.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myFunction();
```

myfile.c

```
#include "myfile.h"

void myFunction(){
    printf("Worked!\n");
}
```

Do you have any idea where this problem can come from?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you compile it?

Comment: simply `gcc main.c`

Comment: And main.c uses myfile.c? You need to add that to the compilation.

Comment: Wow thanks! That was my bad!! it works thank you!

Comment: Good :) - you don't need to include header files though.